# How to use REGEX in this case?

Tags: php, regex

This is my patterns :

"X+X" => Example : 10+9

"X+X+X" => Example : 8+10+9

"X+(X+X)+X" => Example : 10+(8+6)+11

This is the rules :

The last number should be always "encapsulated" between italic marker like this : `"10+<i>9</i>" , "8+10+<i>9</i>"`

If two "+" symbols are present, the content between two "+" should be in bold like this : `"8+<b>10</b>+<i>9</i>", "10+(<b>8+6</b>)+<i>11</i>`

Have you an idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
echo preg_replace(array('/\((.*)\)/','/\+([0-9])+\+/','/[0-9]+$/'), array('(<b>$1</b>)','+<b>$1</b>+','<i>$0</i>'), '11+5+3');
```

Comment: No, an error is get : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')'

Comment: @bahamut100 try now you have an old version of php, arrays can also be declared as [] after 5.4

Comment: Ok, it's work when this pattern is used : 11+(5+4)+3.
But it's not working for : 11+5+3

Comment: @bahamut100 fine try now